# How do I enable edit button on Mobile for the Main Page of a MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I've enabled editing and it is available to all users on all pages but on mobile it is only available to users on all the pages except the Main Page.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit it by manually entering URL

> index.php?title=Main_page&action=edit&section=0

and set section to section you would like to edit (strating with 0 being 1st section, 1 being 2nd section etc).

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to make the edit button available for everyone on the section of the Main Page like it is available for every other page. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I was also looking for solution, that's how I found your question. It looks like bug to me. Another workaround that I found is switching to Desktop View (link is on the bottom of wiki page) edit in Desktop View and then switch back to Mobile View. But edit button would still be missing on mobile view on Main Page.